# SQL Last activity of given type

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

So I have a Visitor table, and a Visitor_activity table. Say:

Visitor

```
Visitor_ID Int
Visitor_name varchar(20)
```

Visitor_Activity

```
ID Int
Visitor_ID Int
Activity_Type char(3) -- values IN or OUT
Activity_Time datetime
```

Visitors might sign in and out multiple times in a day.

I'd like a nice query to tell me all visitors who are in: i.e. the last activity for today (on activity_time) was an "IN" not an "OUT". Any advice much appreciated. 
It's T-SQL by the way, but I think it's more of an in-principle question.

Comment: What if their last activity was IN on yesterday?  Does it have to be today, or just their last activity in general?  How is their "last activity" defined? Are you wanting the most recent Activity_Time or the greatest ID (presumably, some sort of identity field)?

Comment: I see a downvote - I would be interested to know why.

Comment: I'll up-vote just to cancel out the down vote. Stack overflow is full of anonymous hit'n'run down voters idiots nowadays. It should be banned.

Comment: Very civil and civic minded of you, thanks. I can take a downvote if there is something amiss, I just couldn't see what might be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    v.*
FROM
    Visitors v
    JOIN Visitor_Activity va ON va.Visitor_ID = v.Visitor_ID
WHERE
    va.Activity_Type = 'IN'
    AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT
                        *
                     FROM
                        Visitor_Activity va_out
                     WHERE
                        va_out.Visitor_ID = va.Visitor_ID
                        AND va_out.Activity_Type = 'OUT'
                        AND va_out.Activity_Time > va.Activity_Time )
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this is to use a correlated not exists predicate:

```
select Activity_Time, Visitor_ID 
from Visitor_Activity t1
where Activity_Type = 'IN'
and not exists (
    select 1 
    from Visitor_Activity
    where Activity_Type = 'OUT'
    and Visitor_ID = t1.Visitor_ID 
    and Activity_Time > t1.Activity_Time
    and cast(Activity_Time as date) = cast(t1.Activity_Time as date)
    )
```

This basically says *get all visitor_id that have type = IN for which there doesn't exists any type = OUT record with a later time (on the same date)*.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2cfd6/1)

Comment: I also like NOT EIXSTS. However I remark. This date checking is not very good. What would happen if I log in at '23:59:59'? And also you can get into troubles if you do not specify aliases in not exist as it is not obvious what Activity_time to use.

Comment: @sidux No need for aliases as the scope resolution will resolve the columns in the not exists query to the table in the from clause, but sure - it would be clearer with aliases for everything. About the date checking I don't quite understand what you think would be the issue? I assumed that the OUT time can't be the same as the IN time.

Comment: It can. For example I'll log-in today at 23:59:59 and tomorrow ant 00:01:00 your query will not work as the date is different

Comment: @sidux The question asks for the last IN for each date; it doesn't matter if you register a IN on the next date.

Comment: Hard to choose, very similar. Infortunately sidux beat you past the post!

Comment: @DavidShields No problem; just realize that our solutions will produce different results.

Answer (score 1):

```
with visitorsInOut as (
    select Visitor_id,
           max(case when Activity_Type = 'in' then Activity_Time else null end) inTime,
           max(case when Activity_Type = 'out' then Activity_Time else null end) outTime
    from   Visitor_Activity
    where  datediff(dd, Activity_Time, getdate()) = 0
    group by Visitor_id)
select Visitor_id
from   visitorsInOut
where  inTime > outTime or outTime is null
```

Comment: Don't you need GROUP BY, since you have aggregate functions?

Answer (score 0):

This uses a CTE to find the activity record with the greatest Activity_Time where the Activity_Type = 'IN' and assigns it RowNum 1. Then you can INNER JOIN the CTE to the Visitor table, filtering by the CTE results where RowNum = 1.

```
; WITH VisAct AS(
    SELECT act.Visitor_ID
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Visitor_ID ORDER BY Activity_Time DESC) AS RowNum
      FROM Visitor_Activity act
     WHERE act.Activity_Type = 'IN'
       AND act.Activity_Time >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
)
SELECT vis.Visitor_ID, vis.Visitor_name
  FROM Visitor vis
 INNER JOIN VisAct act
    ON act.Visitor_ID = vis.Visitor_ID
 WHERE act.Row_Num = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the most recent action for each visitor, and then only return those where the last action for today was to check in.

```
SELECT v.Visitor_ID, v.Visitor_Name, va.Activity_Type, va.Activity_Time
    FROM Visitor AS v
    INNER JOIN (SELECT Visitor_ID, Activity_Type, Activity_Time, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Visitor_ID ORDER BY Activity_Time DESC) AS LastAction
        FROM Visitor_Activity
        -- checks for today, can be omitted if you still want 
        -- to see someone checked in from yesterday
        WHERE DATEDIFF(d, 0, Activity_Time) = DATEDIFF(d, 0, getdate())
        ) AS va ON va.Visitor_ID = v.Visitor_ID 
    WHERE LastAction = 1
    AND Activity_Type = 'IN'
```

Answer (score 0):

With `CROSS APPLY`:

```
DECLARE @d DATE = '20150320'

DECLARE @v TABLE
    (
      visitor_id INT ,
      visitor_name NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )
DECLARE @a TABLE
    (
      visitor_id INT ,
      type CHAR(3) ,
      time DATETIME
    )


INSERT  INTO @v
VALUES  ( 1, 'A' ),
        ( 2, 'B' ),
        ( 3, 'C' )

INSERT  INTO @a
VALUES  ( 1, 'in', '2015-03-20 19:32:27.513' ),
        ( 1, 'out', '2015-03-20 19:32:27.514' ),
        ( 1, 'in', '2015-03-20 19:32:27.515' ),
        ( 2, 'in', '2015-03-20 19:32:27.516' ),
        ( 2, 'out', '2015-03-20 19:32:27.517' ),
        ( 3, 'in', '2015-03-20 19:32:27.518' ),
        ( 3, 'out', '2015-03-20 19:32:27.519' ),
        ( 3, 'in', '2015-03-20 19:32:27.523' )

SELECT  *
FROM    @v v
        CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    *
                      FROM      ( SELECT TOP 1
                                            type
                                  FROM      @a a
                                  WHERE     a.visitor_id = v.visitor_id
                                            AND a.time >= @d
                                            AND a.time < DATEADD(dd, 1, @d)
                                  ORDER BY  time DESC
                                ) i
                      WHERE     type = 'in'
                    ) c
```

Output:

```
visitor_id  visitor_name    type
1           A               in 
3           C               in
```

The principle:

1. First you are selecting all visitors.
2. Then you are applying to visitor last activity

> ```
> SELECT TOP 1
>         type
> FROM    @a a
> WHERE   a.visitor_id = v.visitor_id
>         AND a.time >= @d
>         AND a.time < DATEADD(dd, 1, @d)
> ORDER BY time DESC
> ```

3. Then you are selecting from previous step in order to get empty set which will filter out visitors whose last activity was not 'in'. If last activity was 'in' you get one row in result and thus applying works. If last activity is 'out' then outer query will result in empty set, and by design `CROSS APPLY` will eliminate such visitor.